# Android background process affinity can't be modified through native code

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-native-interface, affinity

The following piece of Android code only produces native threads running on the same CPU core. `FaceEngineWrapper.Run()` is a JNI wrapper for a face detect inference engine and spawns quite a lot native threads (through both std::thread and openmp in OpenCV-dnn). But these native threads end up running on the same CPU core and the whole process runs very slow.

So how to make native threads utilize all CPU cores?

```
Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Boolean> e) throws Exception {
        e.onNext(true);
        getFrameBitmap();
        e.onComplete();
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mFaceEngineWrapper.Run(); 
            }
        }).start();
      }
});
```

P.S. This app  is tested on an Android RK3399 board, 2/4 big/litte core. The app with jni shared lib consumes 16-17% cpu and the standalone executable binary  with same code and root priviledge consumes 34-35% cpu. If I enable some extra features, the cpu usage goes to about 60% for binary and this app still runs at 17% cpu while the whole delecting process gets much slower. So I guess this app's cpu usage is somehow restricted.

P.P.S. The problem is about cpu affinity. I got CPU-set mask 000001 on this 6-core CPU. But by `sched_setaffinity` to 111111 nothing changed and no error was returned. I really wonder why CPU affinity is set implicitly here and what I can do to disable it.

`SetCpuAffinity({0,1})` is the C++ code called in the working thread (created by `std::thread` in `Run`). `sched_setaffinity` returns 0. But `sched_getaffinity` shows `000001` afterwards. I can't use pthread to do it because Android's pthread lib does not provide affinity function.

```
void SetCpuAffinity(const std::vector<int32_t>& cpuids) {
  int32_t nproc = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
  cpu_set_t cpu_set;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpu_set);
  for (auto&& cpuid: cpuids) {
    if (cpuid >= nproc || cpuid < 0) {
      LOG_ERROR("cannot set affinity cpu id to " << cpuid << " total cpu " << nproc);
    }
    CPU_SET(cpuid, &cpu_set);
  }
  int32_t res = sched_setaffinity(gettid(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu_set);
  LOG_INFO("try to set thread cpu affinity, res "<< res << ", errno " << errno);
  TestThreadAffinity();
  TestThreadCpu();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need a `new Thread` instead of using a thread pool?

Comment: What number does [availableProcessors()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors()) return? It is absolutely up to Android to tell you less than you physically have, and you can't do anything about it just with Java code.

Comment: How do you know all those threads are running on the same core?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki C++ code will manage its own threads. Thread in Java seems quite irrevelant.

Comment: @PavelZdenek I'm using a 2/4 big/litte core arm device. The worker threads are created by c++ std::thread. Java code basically acts as a `main` in c++.

Comment: @reasonsolo Threads in Java are not irrelevant, it is real native threads. You can affine the Java threads to specific core, you just can't do it in Java alone. If your Java code just acts as main(), why bother creating threads at all? Rearchitecting your JNI interface to not block the Run() call may be all that you need.

Comment: @PavelZdenek This is irrelevant because I've tried. Blocking and non-blocking `Run`, `new Thread ()` or not makes no difference. And of course I understand affinity should be managed in C++ code. But it's not changed after `sched_setaffinity`. That's my problem now.

Comment: This is not possible to discuss usefully without deeper knowledge of your app structure. If there is no difference between blocking and non-blocking `Run`, i suspect the performance problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. For Android background service, its affinity is restricted to one CPU core. You can't change it through `sched_setaffinity` or event `tasket -p 3f PID` root command, because the PID is in the `/dev/cpuset/background/tasks` list.

After `echo PID > /dev/cpuset/foreground/tasks` and `echo PID > /dev/cpuset/top-app/tasks`, the PID's affinity can be set by `taskset -p mask PID`.

But the running speed of my service is still quite slow, maybe its thread affinity is not changed instantly(?). And I'm not sure about the default affinity behaviour can be managed through code (either java or native but without root). Really appreciate it if someone would provide a more detailed answer.